# How to add a auto increment numeric value for a file? Such that The value increases when the file is downloaded or viewed

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an article on my website which can be downloaded as PDF and also can be read online. I want to add a number value to my file, such that numeric value changes every time when the file is downloaded or viewed.

Comment: Please post you code.

Comment: Do you mean to add this number value to the file _name_? I would not do that. Perhaps you're talking about a seperated file in which you want to maintain a counter?

Comment: Add increment counter to the file link and better to save it in the database.

Comment: add onclick event and make the increment in database for that particular file through ajax call

Answer (score 0):

you mean you need to show view counts and download counts for your article 
it will not be auto increment 
for that when any one view or download article you have to increment value for that download or view respectively from coding

Comment: okay Thanks,  But how can we know, How many times our file is downloaded. Is there any tool to monitor the downloads.

Comment: instated of any tool for download you can simply write function from where first you can increment download value in database and then return download file , that means you need to call that function on download link